# How is the following code automatically thread safe?

Tags: c#, multithreading, task

I have the following code tin which two threads are adding new elements in a List.

```
public class Numbers
        {
            public int number;
            public string threadName;
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            List<Numbers> numbers = new List<Numbers>();

            Task t = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
                for (int i = 0; i < 999; i++)
                {
                    numbers.Add(new Numbers() { number = i, threadName = "t" });

                }
            });
            Task k = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < 999; i++)
                {
                    numbers.Add(new Numbers() { number = i, threadName = "k" });
                }
            });


            t.Wait();
            k.Wait();


            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("text.txt");

            foreach (var item in numbers)
            {
                writer.WriteLine(item.threadName + item.number);
            }
            writer.Flush();
            Console.WriteLine("Done!");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

When I open the text file I see them are perfectly aligned from  k0k1...k999t0t1...t999 . But I was expecting the list to be mixed or shuffled. Why don't these two tasks add new elements in a random way,but they are sorted perfectly instead?

Comment: Probably because your tasks finish _very_ fast, and the first one finishes before the second is even set up? Not that `List<T>` isn't thread-safe anyway, so as soon as you get both tasks running truly parallell, you'll get exceptions thrown from `Add()`.

Comment: @CodeCaster You are always right. I added a little thread sleep after adding the element and yes they are unpredictable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your tasks are definitely not thread-safe, because they are writing to the same list concurrently. The most likely reason why you get the results that you see is that the first task completes very quickly - it finishes writing all 999 objects before the second task gets a chance to start.

If you add a random short delay to the implementation of your task, you will see some randomness to the results. Making your tasks do more work would probably add some randomness, too: for example, if you make your list a `List<string>` and construct your strings as you go, the second task might start before the first one finishes.

Comment: Task `k` will never execute until `t` finishes.

Comment: @M.kazem I don't think so. `Task.Factory.StartNew()` starts the task immediately. The `Wait()`s are just there so the code only _continues_ after both tasks finish.

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary It will definitely start, and may actually finish. ([`TaskFactory.StartNew` documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321439%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)).

Comment: You are absolutely right. After adding a Thread.Sleep(10) after the line that adds new element, the result became unpredictable. I will accept the answer in 2 minutes.

Comment: @ozgur  `Task.Delay` is more appropriate than sleep.

Comment: @Crowcoder I know. But I am just experimenting, not actually creating an application. That's why I am using some weird things.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.its weird. i didnt know sequential  `Wait`s execute together.